# Couldn't log into gitlab by default account

Tags: gitlab

I have successfully installed the gitlab in my vps.I access to my login page,and fill the default account info(root/5iveL!fe) in the input and then commit.But it will notice that 'Invaild email or password'.I have no idea whether there's some setting detail I have ignored.
Could you please help me?Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi. In your gitlab configuration, did you enable loggin by LDAP ? This settings is in a file called `gitlab.rb`. I remember on old gitlab instance (6.x) when I was enabling LDAP connection I wasn't able to loggin anymore with root/5iveL!fe; I was able to loggin only trough the LDAP.

Comment: @jeanMarcAssin Thanks for your answer.I have tried the new version which   is 7-10-stable instead of 7-3-stable,and I aslo follow ther step of the document,now it can works.I don't know why,but thank you all the same.